# How to make links in an embedded SVG file open in the main window, not in a separate object

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG file (generated by [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/)) that contains URL links. I would like these links to be clickable. First I tried

```
<img src="path/to/my.svg"/>
```

which displays the image fine but the links are not clickable. Changing to object:

```
 <object data="/path/to/my.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

makes the links clickable, but when the user clicks on them, the new page opens inside the object. Is there any way that I can make the links open in the main window?

This is using firefox 5.0, but if there are any cross-browser differences you know about I would appreciate the warning!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First, if you embed SVG as `<img>`, browsers won't open links, as well as they wont run scripts inside `<img>`, because, well, you embed an image, and very probably your image may appear inside an `<a>`, and you can't put links inside links.

And to make links open in new tabs, you can use either the `target` attribute, like in HTML, or xlink-specific `xlink:show` attribute with the value `new`. The SVG spec [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#XLinkShowAttribute) the following:

> [xlink:show] attribute  is provided for backwards compatibility with SVG 1.1. It provides documentation to XLink-aware processors. In case of a conflict, the target attribute has priority, since it can express a wider range of values.

And the values of the `target` attribute can be:

- _replace
- _self
- _parent
- _top
- _blank

Thus, in your SVG you need to write as follows:

```
<a xlink:href="http://example.com" target="_blank">[...]</a>
```

But currently all browsers capable of showing SVG support both `xlink:show` and `target` attributes (I haven't tested in IE9 though).

Comment: He wants to open it in the containing window.  I think you want "_parent" or "_top".

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for these two answers. Adding a `target='_top'` to my Graphviz HTML label gives the result I was looking for.

Comment: Note, as in the posted example, that it must be 'target=', not 'xlink:target=' (even though you want 'xlink:href=').  This tripped me up for a bit.

Comment: xlink:show="new" target="_top" worked for me in Chromium.

Comment: target="_top" worked for me, but is there any way I can implement this in a single, general declaration, rather than having to add this attribute manually on every link? This seems like an awful lot of unnecessary work; I want to override the default behavior universally, for all links in an SVG.

Comment: @cazort I don't know an exact answer to your question, but depending on how you embed SVG, you can add `<base target="_blank" />` to your `<head>` element and all links in the document will open in new tab. Should  help if you embed SVG in an HTML iframe.

Comment: Thanks! Setting base target="_blank" didn't work. I'm embedding the SVG using <object>. I don't know if there's a way to do it with this or not.