# Links missing in SVG Sphinx inheritance diagrams

Tags: svg, hyperlink, graphviz, python-sphinx

When I configure [Sphinx's Graphviz](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/graphviz.html) extension to generate SVG output, using

```
graphviz_output_format = 'svg'
```

I am no longer able to click on the nodes of inheritance diagrams generated using the [`inheritance_diagram` extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/inheritance.html).

Is there a way to enable these links in an SVG diagram, or do they only work for PNG diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience with embedded dot graphs (`graphviz` directive in Sphinx). Doing a little digging (and testing), I've concluded:

1. When setting `graphviz_output_format` to `png`, sphinx handles this by doing a few extra things:

   1. It has dot output both a `.png` and a corresponding `.map` file.
   2. The rendered HTML includes a map section to "overlay" the png image with link targets.
2. When using `SVG`, the renderer omits the map section and only produces an SVG image. Since SVG supports links within the format (which dot correctly embeds), I presume it was expected the map section was redundant (or more likely problematic since it would "compete" with the SVG-rendered image for focus.)

   3. As alluded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008355/how-to-make-links-in-an-embedded-svg-file-open-in-the-main-window-not-in-a-sepa), most browsers disable embedded SVG links (when surrounded by a `<img>` tag). The consequence is that the embedded links are not visible, and thus not clickable.

---

In my case when I open the SVG image directly in the browser, the embedded links are clickable (tested on Safari and Firefox).