# SVG Image Map in Wordpress - Hyperlinks do not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, svg

I am trying to set up an interactive map the visitor can use to navigate through scientific methodes. The SVG works flawlessly but Wordpress disables the hyperlinks within the image. I know this is due to security but I still want to get this going. Any ideas how this could work?

[Link of Page](http://www.bakerstreet.uni-bremen.de/methoden/)

[Link of Image](http://imgh.us/Map_5.svg)

Embedding:
[image: ImageMap]

Would appreciate any help. Also I am no learned programmer, so I need a while to wrap my head around stuff.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make links in an embedded SVG file open in the main window, not in a separate object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008355/how-to-make-links-in-an-embedded-svg-file-open-in-the-main-window-not-in-a-sepa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an SVG is embedded as an `<img>`, it is embedded as a bitmap. Any animation or interaction, such as links, are lost.

The normal solution is to embed your SVG as an `<object>` instead.  However I am not an expert on Wordpress, so I can't offer advice on how to do that part.